# How to mix XML layout with java programing

Tags: java, xml

I am very new to programing android apps. I am good with java but I'm not a fan of XML. From what I have read it is possible to use XML for the layout and java for doing the main functions but I can't find a good tutorial for it, probably because I suck at searching lol. But anyways does anyone know of a good tutorial I can use or just a site to get me started down the right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. Actually, you don't use xml for functions (that would be torture). You put your xml layouts in the `/layout` folder and then refer to elements to do stuff (like add listeners/whatnot) by doing something like `Button yourButton = (Button) <Activity instance>.findViewByID(R.id.your_button)`.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

And if you really don't like xml, you can just do everything in java...

Comment: Ohh now I know why I was so lost lol. I thought they we're suppose to be separate. Thanks that helped out a lot I feel stupid now XD